# Insertion Sorting c#

Tags: c#, insertion-sort

Can you guys please help me with basic insertion sorting in C#. I have a list of names and city of residence in a array and need to sort this array by comparing the city of residence. List has to be sorted in alphabetical order. Comparator has been set up and works I'm just kinda lost with the insertion sorter programming as this is the first time we are doing that method of sorting.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```csharp
public void InsertionSort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        Student cur = Attendees[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < Count; j++)
        {
            Student Sel = Attendees[j];
            if (cur.CompareTo(Sel) < 0)
            {
                Student temp = Attendees[j];
                Attendees[j] = Attendees[i];
                for (int k = i; k > j; k--)
                    Attendees[k] = Attendees[k - 1];
                Attendees[k + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Steps : 1- Edit your question. 2- Post some attempts/code. Results : get less downvotes + get answers/suggestions.

Comment: Google is your friend! Here is one shoot: http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array/

Comment: public void InsertionSort()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                Student cur = Attendees[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < Count; j++)
                {
                    Student Sel = Attendees[j];
                    if (cur.CompareTo(Sel) < 0)
                    {
                        Student temp = Attendees[j];
                        Attendees[j] = Attendees[i];

                        for (int k = i; k > j; k--)
                            Attendees[k] = Attendees[k - 1];
                            Attendees[k + 1] = temp;

Comment: thats about how far i got

Comment: just looking for a hint as to were to start or if im on the right track

Comment: Your code was missing the closing brackets. I closed all brackets, but since I'm not you, I don't know if I put them right.

Comment: The comments above is extremely unhelpful to a newbie - just answer his question, hes given u an example. Phew!!

Comment: @private If by "example" you mean the code; it wasn't there until it got edited in, 20 minutes after the question got posted. As you can see, all "unhelpful" comments were written well before the code was even visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this...

```
public void InsertionSort()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        While(j > 0)
        {
            Student cur = Attendees[j];
            Student sel = Attendees[j-1];
            if (cur.CompareTo(Sel) < 0)
            {
                Student temp = cur;
                cur = sel;
                sel = temp;
                j--
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void InsertionSort()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < Count; i++) // Iterate beginning at 1, because we assume that 0 is already sorted
    {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) // Iterate backwards, starting from 'i'
        {
            Student cur = Attendees[j - 1];
            Student tbs = Attendees[j]; // 'tbs' == "to be sorted"
            if (cur.CompareTo(tbs) < 0) // usually, classes that implement 'CompareTo()' also implement 'operator <()', 'operator >()' and 'operator ==()', so you could have just written 'cur < tbs'
            {
                Student temp = Attendees[j];
                Attendees[j] = Attendees[j - 1];
                Attendees[j - 1] = temp;
            }
            else
                break; // since 'tbs' is no longer > 'cur', it is part of our sorted list. We don't need to sort that particular 'tbs' any further
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that this algorithm sorts your list in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] newarr = {2,1,5,3,7,6};
int a, b;
for (int i = 1; i < newarr.Length; i++)
{
    a = newarr[i];
    b = i - 1;
    while(b>=0 && newarr[b]>a)
    {
        newarr[b+1] = newarr[b];
        b=b-1;
    }
    newarr[b+1] = a;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.